# vb6 check to see if textbox is empty

Tags: textbox, vb6

There is a similar question to this but it is for C#,  [Check if TextBox is empty and return MessageBox?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6156458/check-if-textbox-is-empty-and-return-messagebox).

There is another solution that check if textbox is empty https://www.daniweb.com/software-development/visual-basic-4-5-6/threads/414651/checking-if-textbox-is-empty, but this works if you are going to check all the textbox in the form. I would like to check some textbox in the form if they are empty or not.

I've written this code to check if textboxes are empty

```
Private sub checkEmpty()
If text1.text = "" Or text2.text="" Then
blank = true
End If
End Sub
```

Then added this code to my command button

```
Private Sub command1_Click()
checkEmpty
If blank = true Then
Msgbox "a text box is empty"
Else
Msgbox "Text box has text"
End If
End Sub
```

The problem when I start the program it gives the output `"Text box has text"`  even if there are no text in the text boxes.

What is wrong with this code?

Comment: change `checkEmpty` to a function returning True or False and evaluate that

Comment: Do you have `Option Explicit` declared at the head of every module as you should?

Answer (score 4):

You need to change your procedure to a function that returns a value (I'd change the name at the same time to make it more clear what it does).

```
Private Function AnyTextBoxEmpty() As Boolean
  AnyTextBoxEmpty = text1.Text = "" or text2.Text = ""
End Function

Private Sub command1_Click()
  If AnyTextBoxEmpty Then
    Msgbox "a text box is empty"
  Else
    Msgbox "Text box has text"
  End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Private Function AnyTextBoxEmpty() AS Boolean ?

Comment: thanks @Ken White. I'm new to this programming stuff and doing only self study, I would very much appreciate if you can direct me where I can get more information regarding this language or other language you want to suggest.

Comment: Every *legitimate* copy of VB6 came with a set of MSDN Library CDs that contain everything in the printed manuals as well as much more.